# Continuously append to the end of an array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Each time I press a button I am trying to append that new number to the end of my array. I have tried a ton of different things, but I can't quite get it.

I have tried the append, insert, creating an empty array and so much more.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var num1 = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var digitCounts = Array(repeating: 0, count: 10)
    var number_list = [1,2,3]

    if num1 >= 0 {

    digitCounts.insert(3, at: num1)
    print(digitCounts)
    number_list.append(num1)
    num1 += 1
    print(num1)
    print(number_list)
    } 
}
```

the result would look like

> starting array [1,2,3] after button pressed first time [1,2,3,4] after
>   button pressed second time [1,2,3,4,5] after button pressed third time
>   [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: You have your code wrapped inside an if checking `num1` is greater than or equal to 0. What is num1, its not defined in your code. When you say its not working, have you seen any printouts at all?

Comment: Updated code: my results are either a number moves a long the array as I press it in the insert function or it just adds the new number to the end of my current array, then replaces that number after I hit the button again.

Comment: You can simply get the last number of your array and increase it. Note that you should declare your array as an instance property of your view controller. Move it out of your IBAction method. `var numbers = [1,2,3]` and `if let last = numbers.last {
    numbers.append(last+1)
}
print(numbers)`

Comment: Array operations nicely explained [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should declare `var number_list` as a `ViewController`'s property:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var number_list = [1,2,3]
}
```

Otherwise `var number_list` with it's default value will be created each time when `button(_ sender:)` is calling.

And use the following handler for your button:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    number_list += number_list.last.flatMap { [$0+1] } ?? []
    print(number_list)
}
```

All code in this post was tested in Xcode 10.2.1. I used Swift 5.

Comment: I think OP wants to increase the value of the last element. Btw the pharenteses it is not needed.  `number_list += number_list.last.flatMap { [$0+1] } ?? []`

Answer (score 0):

Ok now that you've shown the full code I can see the problem. You are creating new arrays every-time you click the button, but are storing `num1` outside of this function.

Try this:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var num1 = 0
 var digitCounts = Array(repeating: 0, count: 10)
 var number_list = [1,2,3]

 @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if num1 >= 0 {
        digitCounts.insert(3, at: num1)
        print(digitCounts)

        number_list.append(num1)
        num1 += 1
        print(num1)
        print(number_list)
    } 
}
```

By storing the arrays as properties of the class, instead of inside the function, they will persist through multiple clicks

Answer (score 0):

you have to make you array global and make changes as follow

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var num1 = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var number_list = [1,2,3]

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var number = number_list.last ?? 0
        number += 1
        number_list.append(number)
        print(number_list)
    }
}
```

Comment: "you have to make you array global" ? You meant "an instance property of your view controller". Global means visible inside any view controller. The only global var in your code is `num1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not multithreading, a simple solution is to remember the last number instead of having to check the last element in the array:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var number_list = [1, 2, 3]
    var num1 = 3

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        number += 1
        number_list.append(number)
        print(number_list)
    }
}
```